# Email content as comment

Tags: plugin-development, comments, email

I am trying to develop a ticketing system. Can I capture reply email content to my ticketing system as comment?

Comment: Theoretically this is possible, but goes beyond the scope of WordPress.

Comment: Yes, you can capture reply email content to your ticketing system as comment. But it's hard to say what you are trying to do until we see some efforts from you in term of some ready-to-use code or algorithm. Do you have an algorithm? At least.

Comment: You'll need a non-WP system to check for replies and run the request to WP to create the comment. WP doesn't have that functionality, and a webapp isn't the best method to monitor an email inbox for replies

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Actually I don't have any algorithm at all. Can you please suggest some samples for me ?